# jQuery checkbox state always reports checked

Tags: jquery, checked

I am using the change function on a checkbox to test if a checkbox is checked or unchecked, but when I check or uncheck the box, it always reports as being checked. Getting the state of the checkbox when the change function triggers seem logical, but I probably have the syntax wrong.

See this fiddle, and thanks for any advice

http://jsfiddle.net/Fx6rK/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="hide_replies" />
<label for="hide_replies">hide replies</label>

$(document).ready(function() {
   var replies_check = $('#hide_replies')
   replies_check.change(function() {
     if ( 'replies_check:checked' ) {
      alert('checked');
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var replies_check = $('#hide_replies')
   replies_check.change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked' )) {
        alert('checked');
    }else{
        alert('not checked');
    }
   });
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fx6rK/3/

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="hide_replies" />
<label for="hide_replies">hide replies</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#hide_replies').click(function() {
     if ( $('#hide_replies').is(':checked') ) {
      alert('checked');
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks - accepted another reply but +1 for a fast, and usable response

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var replies_check = $('#hide_replies')
   replies_check.change(function() {
       if (replies_check.is(":checked")) {
       alert('checked');
       }
   });
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fx6rK/4/)

Comment: Thanks - accepted another reply but +1 for a fast, and usable response

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var replies_check = $('#hide_replies');
   replies_check.change(function() {
   alert($('#hide_replies').is(':checked') );
  });
});
```